# Django 1.8 inspectdb command doesn't see PostgreSQL views as per documentation

Tags: python, django, postgresql, view

I have a Django 1.8 application with a PostgreSQL database. I run the django inspectdb from the command line to examine models for the views, but the views don't show up in the model output.

Here's the version output:

```
17:36 $ python well/manage.py --version
1.8.2
```

And here's what psql sees:

```
\dv
                List of relations
 Schema |             Name              | Type |  Owner  
--------+-------------------------------+------+---------
 public | hospitalizations_over_30_days | view | dwatson
 public | interval_30_days              | view | dwatson
(2 rows)
```

From the django 1.8.2 documentation:

```
New in Django 1.8:
A feature to inspect database views was added. In previous versions, only tables (not views) were inspected.
```

How can I get the PostgreSQL views to appear in the Django 1.8.2 inspectdb output?

Comment: any success finding a solution?

Comment: you ever get this working?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of Django 1.10, you can simply name an individual view as a parameter to your `inspectdb` command:

```
python well/manage.py inspectdb hospitalizations_over_30_days
```

The default `inspectdb` will only output models.py for tables, but models for views can be generated individually by naming them.

In Django 2.1 and above, if you want `inspectdb` to generate models for all tables *and* views, [use the `inspectdb --include-views`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.1/) option, which I [contributed to Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.1/) as a result of this question!

```
python well/manage.py inspectdb --include-views
```

To generate models for both tables and views in Django 2.0 and below, you have to edit the Django source code. In Django 2.0, change [line 57 in `django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/85e6a1c634fed55c43090e37b802c721d9e7eaaa/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py#L57) to:

```
tables_to_introspect = options['table'] or connection.introspection.table_names(cursor=cursor, include_views=True)
```

Beware that the generated models won't have fields with `primary_key=True` set, you will need to add primary keys manually.

Comment: Thank you. A doubt... do you know how to create this view dinamically by migrations, as well as we do with the common tables?

Answer (score 6):

In recent releases, there is an option to include views by passing it to the command as follows (both tables and views will be inspected):

```
python manage.py inspectdb --include-views > my_models.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner,Not sure whether it add more value. Still As an extension to the answers.
Once we setup the settings.py,if we got multiple schemas and just need specific view.

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database [alias name for the database connection string in settings.py] --include-views [name of the view]>model.py
```

May be its helpful for beginners.