# GeoDjango inspectdb with multiple databases

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to run `inspectdb` on a PostgreSQL DB with Postgis.

To generate the model for a postgresql view, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47679397/3976696) that I should use the command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database my_schema my_view> my_view_legacy.py
```

But because of PostGIS, `inspectdb` also tries to access a view in another schema, which raises the following error when it encounters a field of type `geometry` in `my_view`:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "geometry_columns" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "coord_dimension", "srid", "type" FROM "geometry_colu...
```

This seems like a [catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)): if I specify the database name so that `inspectdb` knows which view to inspect, it cannot find find the `geometry_columns` view in the `public` schema. But if I don't specify any database name, it cannot find `my_view` in the first place.

Is there any solution to this?

My database schemas are defined as:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': 
            {
            },

    'public': 
            {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'OPTIONS': {
                            'options': '-c search_path=public'
                        },
            'NAME': 'my_db',
            'USER': secrets.USER,
            'PASSWORD': secrets.PASSWORD,
            'HOST': 'my.host.addr',
            'PORT': '5432',
            },

    'my_schema': 
            {
            'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis', 
            'OPTIONS': {
                            'options': '-c search_path=my_schema'
                        },
            'NAME': 'my_db',
            'USER': secrets.USER,
            'PASSWORD': secrets.PASSWORD,
            'HOST': 'my.host.addr',
            'PORT': '5432',
            },    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated the *`geometry_columns`* and *`geography_columns`* in the specified schema, so that GeoDjango could find them.